# add property to object in state array with useReducer

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, use-reducer

I have an array of objects stored in state that looks like:

```
    {
        "file": {},
        "myFsize": 1321,
        "fileType": "image/jpeg"
    },
{
        "file": {},
        "myFsize": 999,
        "fileType": "image/jpeg"
    }
]
```

I am using `useHookReducer` to add and remove objects successfully

`const [fileSelectedArrax, setfileSelectedArrax] = useReducer(fileSelectReducer, [])`

however I want to also add an upload progress to each object as it uploads. It shhould look like this...

```
    {
        "file": {},
        "myFsize": 1321,
        "fileType": "image/jpeg",
        "percent": "90"
    },
{
        "file": {},
        "myFsize": 999,
        "fileType": "image/jpeg",
        "percent": "100"

    }
]
```

This is my reducer:

```
function fileSelectReducer(state, action) {
   switch (action.type) {
      case 'add':
         console.log(state)
         return [...state, action.filex]
      case 'adduploadprogress':
         //WHAT HERE?
        return [...state]
      case 'remove':
         const update = [...state]
         update.splice(update.indexOf(action.file), 1)
         document.getElementById(fileattach).value = ''
         return update
      default:
         return state
    }
}
```

My function to invoke this is:

```
function adduploadprogress({ file, percent }) {
   const filex = { file, percent }
   console.log(filex)
   setfileSelectedArrax({ filex, type: 'adduploadprogress' })
}
```

I have tried `for loops` and ternerys to match the object in state to the file being passed in in the action, but nothing seems to work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can map the array of files (the `state`), and replace the current file's object with a new object that contains the new `percent`:

```
case 'adduploadprogress':
  return state.map(f => f.file === action.filex.file ? ({ 
    ...f,
    percent: action.filex.percent,
  }) : f)
```

Comment: This is perfect thanks so much. Where should I put the key index to stop the error from the map please?

Comment: You can use the file as key. You need to add the "key" attribute when you render - https://reactjs.org/docs/lists-and-keys.html

Comment: Thanks.I thought the usual ket error was coming from this for some reason, but it was from somewhere else. Thanks again